# testcafe works properly for individual test but all tests

Tags: javascript, testing, testcafe, ui-testing, test-framework

I'm new in testcafe. Here is the issue I confronted recently. Please shine some light:

Say I got four testcafe tests, say A, B, C and D

1. It works smoothly if I run them one by one, *testcafe chrome A.js*, *testcafe chrome B.js* and so on
2. Now I grab all my tests in a folder named tests then run it by using:
   testcafe chrome

After step2, only the first three tests work as desired(all pass), test D will always failed for suspending in the loading page, then Selector cannot locate the right button:

[loading page -- undesired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySVqN.png)

Here is the desired page which will showup in previous three tests:

[desired page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOp8l.png)

Can someone shining light on this issue?

Comment: Test run result shouldn't depend on tests count in the task. Could you please provide me with your test scripts? It hard to determine the cause of  the issue without it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Test script can be found here [link](https://github.com/ww8912188/testcafe-test/blob/master/tests/check3D.js).
I invoked my test using node runner_3D.js.

Comment: We've found the cause of your problem and we've created an [issue #1546](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1546) in our repository. You can subscribe on it to be notified about our progress.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up, we have fixed the issue described in this thread:

[Clear out the localStorage after testing](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1546)